# MySQL select avg reading every hour even if there is no reading

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time making a MySQL statement from a Postgres one for a project we are migrating. I won't give the exact use case since it's pretty involved, but I can create a simple comparable situation.

We have a graphing tool that needs somewhat raw output for our data in hourly intervals. In Postgres, the SQL would generate a series for the date and hour over a time span, then it would join a query against that for the average where that date an hour existed. We were able to get for example the average sales by hour, even if that number is 0.

Here's a table example:

```
Sales
datetime            | sale
2017-12-05 08:34:00 | 10
2017-12-05 08:52:00 | 20
2017-12-05 09:15:00 | 5
2017-12-05 10:22:00 | 10
2017-12-05 10:49:00 | 10
```

Where something like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(s.datetime,'%Y%m%d%H') as "byhour", AVG(s.sale) as "avg sales" FROM sales s  GROUP BY byhour
```

would produce

```
byhour     | avg sales
2017120508 | 10
2017120509 | 5
2017120510 | 10
```

I'd like something that gives me the last 24 hours, even the 0/NULL values like

```
byhour     | avg sales
2017120501 | null
2017120502 | null
2017120503 | null
2017120504 | null
2017120505 | null
2017120506 | null
2017120507 | null
2017120508 | 10
2017120509 | 5
2017120510 | 10
...
2017120600 | null
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Join the result on a table that you know contains all the desired hours

someting like this:

```
SELECT 
* FROM (
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(s.datetime, '%Y%m%d%H') AS 'byhour'
FROM
    table_that_has_hours
GROUP BY byhour) hours LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(s.datetime, '%Y%m%d%H') AS 'byhour',
        AVG(s.sale) AS 'avg sales'
FROM
    sales s
GROUP BY byhour) your_stuff ON your_stuff.byhour = hours.by_hours
```

if you don't have a table like that you can create one.
like this:

`CREATE TABLE ref (h INT);`

`INSERT INTO ref (h)
    -> VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),
    -> (12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)`

and then you can just  `DATE_FORMAT(date(now()),'%Y%m%d%H')` to the values

Comment: I was hoping to avoid seeding a table for this, but I'm starting to think it's the cleanest way. Since I'm converting a postgres project to mysql, I was trying to keep it as identical as possible, but there might be too many differences